# ¿Como puedo enviar una sola id de toda una lista en php?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

[image: Tengo una lista de preguntas y opciones y al dar gurdar necesito que se que inserte la id de la pregunta y la opcion, pero simpre se me gurda la id de la ultima pregunta, es por que se me envian todas las ids de las preguntas y no se como puedo hacer para que se envie la seleccionada]

*Necesito enviar pregunta_id de la pregunta que selecciono para poder isertar en un tabla la pregunta y la opcion seleccionadas pero se me envia todas las ids de las preguntas y se me inserta simpre la id de la ultima pegunta*

```
<?php while($preguntas = $resultado->fetch_assoc())  { ?>
               
                        
               <div class="post-preview">
               <hr>
                   <a>
                       <h2 class="post-title">
                       <?php while($id = $docente->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                           <input type="hidden" name="docente_id" id="docente_id" value="<?php echo $id['docente_id']; ?>">
                       <?php } ?>    

                       <input type="hidden" name="pregunta_id" id="pregunta_id" value="<?php echo $preguntas['pregunta_id']; ?>">
                       <?php
                       echo '<li type="text"><span>'.$preguntas['item'].'</span></li>';
                       ?>
                       </h2>
                   
                   <p class="post-meta">       
                   <?php  
                   $sql = " SELECT * FROM opciones";
                   $resultado2 = $conn->query($sql);

                   while($opciones = $resultado2->fetch_assoc()){
                       echo '<li><input name="opcion_id" id="opcion_id" type="radio" value="'.$opciones['opcion_id'].'"><span>'.$opciones['opcion_nombre'].'</span></li>';
                    } ?>

                        <input type="hidden" name="registro" value="nuevo">
                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-info btn-sm"><i class="far fa-save"></i> &nbsp; GUARDAR</button>
                   </p>
                   </a>
               </div>
                   <?php } ?>  
          </div>
```

Comment: Supongo que la acción se lanza al pulsar en el botón `GUARDAR` ... Lo propio sería controlar los listeners de tus elementos, sabiendo identificar en qué botón se hizo clic y tomando el `pregunta_id` propio de ese ámbito. En Javascript es relativamente fácil hacer eso, es cuestión de organizar tu código, por ejemplo, se pueden agrupar los elementos en clases y poner un listener a esas clases y buscar dentro de ellas el primer input, por poner un ejemplo. En pocas palabras, lo que necesitas es organizar las escuchas. No sé si me explico, si no, aclara un poco mejor la pregunta y te ayudamos.

Comment: Hola, si es exactamente lo que pretendo hacer, pero como puedo agruparlo por clases ?

Comment: Podrías por ejemplo crear un `div class="unaClase">` por cada grupo de elementos, luego asignas un listener que escuche a los elementos con `unaClase` y luego, dependiendo del contexto puedes saber el valor de un determinado `input` u otro elemento de **esa clase**. En Javascript hay muchos tipos de selectores que hacen eso, por ejemplo los ancestros, por tipos, etc. En lenguaje llano, podrías por ejemplo saber: *el valor del primer `input` de **esa clase** o el valor del tercer `li` de esa clase, o el valor del 5º `td` que está después del 2º `input` de **esa clase*** o cosas más complejas.

Comment: A ya entiendo voy a intentarlo, Gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Es que deberías pasar un arreglo a tu `$_POST`, ahí estás pasando solo el último valor. Si ves en el código `HTML` generado, verás como `pregunta_id` se pasa solo el último valor.

Vamos, otra forma de verlo es que en la página a la que liga el `action`, pongas lo siguiente, para ver qué te estás llevando en el `$_POST`:

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
</pre>
<?php die(); ?>
... el resto de tu código...
```

Verás que solo te llevas UNA variable (la última) en `preungta_id`. Una forma de corregirlo es que hagas algo así (pseudocódigo):

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($opciones = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    <input name="pregunta_id[$i]" value="..." type="radio">
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Ahora pruebas lo del `<pre><?php print_r($_POST); ?></pre>` y verás que te estás llevando un arreglo y no solo una variable, una vez que asegures eso, quitas el código de debug y ya puedes iterar sobre el arreglo que estás recibiendo.

¿Me explico?

Comment: Pero no seria de agregar ese codigo en el while de la pregunta ?
o por que va en el de la opcion ?
Gracias de ante mano

Comment: De hecho, sería en los dos. Uno para las preguntas y otro para las respuestas con el $i como índice sincronizado

Comment: Amigo una pregunta lo he heco asi pero y ahora como hago para resivir los datos en el modelo osea cono recibo los name si estan con ese codigo ?